# PayPal transaction has expired

Tags: java, paypal

I am using paypal rest API to process payments using paypal express checkout method in a java web application and currently application is point to paypal sandbox. We were testing transactions without problem until recently but suddenly it is not working now, did not do any coding changes also,

now when redirect to paypal site for user approval, always getting a page saying,

```
This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website  to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow

We're sorry, but your session has ended. Your account hasn't been charged. Please go back to the merchant's site and check out again with PayPal.
```

I am getting redirect URL(approval URL) in java as bellow

```
private String getApprovalURL(Payment payment)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String redirectUrl = null;
    List<Links> links = payment.getLinks();     
    for (Links l : links) {
        if (l.getRel().equalsIgnoreCase("approval_url")) {
            redirectUrl = URLDecoder.decode(l.getHref(), "UTF-8");
            break;
        }
    }
    return redirectUrl;
}
```

and I am getting redirect URL similar to following,

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6U3345417C9052027
```

what could be the reason for this behavior? any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have encountered this issue as well. We resolved it by modifying the return url we received from paypal callback and explicitly add the `sandbox` to the url before redirecting it.

Actual Url received:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6U3345417C9052027

Modified Url:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-6U3345417C9052027